# Python - time: how to check if seconds == 00

Tags: python, datetime, time, schedule

In my script I want to run a function when the seconds are 00. For example if I start the script at 8:12:32, I want the function to start at 8:13:00.
I have tried to use the datetime.datetime.now() but haven't figured out how to sort out the seconds from the time. In the Python 3 documentation I have also found time.second and datetime.second but i haven't had any success using them.

Comment: Tried `datetime.datetime.now().second`?

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime, time
delta = 60 - datetime.datetime.now().second
time.sleep(delta)
```

The next statement will be executed on the minute (`hh:mm:00`).

Comment: Just wanted to post the exact same thing. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `time.time()` and `time.sleep()` to sleep till the start of the next minute with sub-second precision:

```
time.sleep(60 - time.time() % 60)
```